# PHP Not Inserting Content in mySQL Database: Text, Images, Anything

Tags: php, html, mysql

So here is my dilemna that I've been reviewing and trying to break through for the last few days. I've created a basic login/register PHP system, which works fine. I've implemented a blog system that displays posts. I've written an add post function which does not post to the database, and it doesn't throw back an error function either.

I don't really understand because my register system works and adds new users, but the 'add blog post' does nothing. I can add from the database and it displays fine, but nothing here.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }

    if ($_POST['submit']) { 
        $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
        $subtitle = strip_tags($_POST['subtitle']);
        $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);

        mysqli_query($dbCon, $userREQ3);
        $userREQ3 = " INSERT INTO `logindb`.`blog` 
        (`title`, `subtitle`, `content`) VALUES ('$title','$subtitle','$content')";

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <head>

   </head>

   <body>
     Welcome, <?php echo $username; ?>, You are logged in. Your user id is <?php echo $userId; ?>.

    <a href="index.php">Index</a>
    <form action="logout.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Log me out!">
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="admin.php">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br>
        Subtitle: <input type="text" name="subtitle"/><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content: <textarea name="content"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Write Post"/>
    </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: write this line after your insert query `mysqli_query($dbCon, $userREQ3);`also not able to see your database connection code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing for two reasons.

- Your conditional statement is looking for a named element called "submit"
- You're trying to execute before the statement. Place your query (`mysqli_query()`)"**below**" the values and do `mysqli_query($dbCon, $userREQ3) or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));`

Sidenote: Change `if ($_POST['submit']) {` to `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` it's better.

and `<input type="submit" value="Write Post"/>`
to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Write Post"/>`

---

SQL injection:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Also, you have variables in the body of your code, which may throw undefined variable x on initial page load.

- Use a ternary operator for this
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- Use this for all your inputs/variables

---

As stated (in comments below): Make sure that you have connected to your database and using a mysqli method and not another API.

- https://secure.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other. Use the same MySQL API from connection to query.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Successful query or not:

To see if the query was indeed successful, or failed, check for errors and use `affected_rows`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

---

> *PHP Not Inserting Content in mySQL Database: Text, **Images,** Anything*

If you were trying to use images, then a valid enctype is required to be included in the form tags.

Depending on how/what you wanted to insert for the images, than that could be a factor.

If you're wanting to insert the image as a path is one thing, but using it "as an image", say a BLOB then that has limitations in size; use LONGBLOB and you must escape that data before going in the database.

Consult:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: welcome +10 form my side. you beat me also on this. ha ha ha

Comment: Also add one key point  to your answer he is not added database connection or include any connection file

Comment: @Saty Duly noted in my answer (edited), thank you for your comment. Every little bit helps, *cheers*

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help - I want to be good and you guys are incredible teachers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the query first, then execute it...

```
$userREQ3 = " INSERT INTO `logindb`.`blog` 
(`title`, `subtitle`, `content`) VALUES ('$title', '$subtitle','$content')";


mysqli_query($dbCon, $userREQ3);
```

Comment: There is a closing brace `}` with no opening brace `{` make sure they make and the code is complete and also explain your code in detail